# Imputing Time based on condition

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I am trying to impute time based on the previous line value.

```
Concat               ID     Date           Time1    Time2
1615 - 2019-05-14   1615   5/14/2019    20:57:56    21:26:45
161 - 2019-05-14    161    5/14/2019    21:52:19    NA
161 - 2019-05-15    161    5/15/2019    NA          1:10:49
161 - 2019-05-14    161    5/17/2019    21:52:19    NA
161 - 2019-05-15    161    5/20/2019    NA          1:10:49
```

For each ID column and if the Date difference is less 2 and if the Time1 is NA and the previous adjacent Time2 is NA, then I want to replace "00:00:01" in Time1 and "23:59:59" in the previous adjacent NA like below.

```
 Concat              ID     Date           Time1    Time2
1615 - 2019-05-14   1615   5/14/2019    20:57:56    21:26:45
161 - 2019-05-14    161    5/14/2019    21:52:19    23:59:59
161 - 2019-05-15    161    5/15/2019    00:00:01    1:10:49
161 - 2019-05-14    161    5/17/2019    21:52:19    NA
161 - 2019-05-15    161    5/20/2019    NA          1:10:49
```

I tried using lead and lag value from dplyr but not able to get that properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a reproducible data example, I can only guess that this would help you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Time1_fixed = ifelse(
      (lag(Date,1)+1 == Date) & # the previous Date was one day before this one
       is.na(Time1) & # AND this Time1 is NA
       is.na(lag(Time2,1)), # AND the previous Time1 was NA
      '00:00:01',
      Time1
    ),
    Time2_fixed = ifelse(
      (lead(Date,1) == Date+1) & # the next Date is one day after this one
       is.na(Time2) & # AND this Time2 is NA
       is.na(lead(Time1,1)), # AND the next Time1 is NA
      '23:59:59',
      Time2
    )
)
```